# How can I automatize a function system

Tags: python, function, loops, for-loop

this maybe simple but how can I automatize this:
for example, this is just for 2 steps but I want to do the same for 100
should I use looping or another kind of function

```
def earn(w,y):
    
    return w+y

def spend(w,x):
    
    new_wealth = w -x
    if new_wealth < 0:
        print("Insufficient funds")
    else:
        return new_wealth
    
w0=0
w1=earn(w0,2300)
w2=spend(w1,1500)
w3=earn(w2,2300)
w4=spend(w3,1500)
print("w0,w1,w2,w3,w4 = ", w0,w1,w2,w3,w4)
```

Comment: When you say this is for 2 steps, do you mean in each step you have an earn-spend operation? You also want to be careful with `spend()`, because if `new_wealth` is negative, you will return `None`, which will throw an error next time you try to do an arithmetic operation with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To repeat the same action, you should obviously use loops.
Here is an example using a "for" loop with 100 iterations, appending each operation result in a list:

```
results = []
w = 0
for _i in range(100):
    w = earn(w, 2300)
    results.append(w)
    w = spend(w, 1500)
    results.append(w)
    
print(results) # [2300, 800, 3100, 1600, 3900, 2400 ... ]
```

You should obviously modify it for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks. I am having serious troubles with python syntax. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

if you had a list of transactions with weather it was a spend or earn and the value you could try something like this

```
transactions = ['earn 2300', 'spend 1500', 'earn 2300', 'spend 1500']

string = ''
results = [0]
for n in range(len(transactions)):
    string += 'w'+str(n)
    transactions_type = transactions[n].split(' ')[0]
    transactions_value = int(transactions[n].split(' ')[1])
    if transactions_type.lower() == 'earn':
        results.append(earn(results[-1], transactions_value))
    if transactions_type.lower() == 'spend':
        results.append(spend(results[-1], transactions_value))
    output = string + ' = '
for value in results:
    output += str(value)
```

which outputs

```
w0,w1,w2,w3,w4 =  0 2300 800 3100 1600
```

but this would depend on how you are storing this transaction information the method here works but is not ideal